# How to execute android function sequentially?

Tags: android

I make a game about 8Puzzle on android with AI using A* algorithm.
Everything works fine but there is a problem, there are some function that is executed in parallel.
What I want is the function is executed after another function is finished.

Here is code:

```
if(AItype.equals("A*"))
{
    DisableButton();
    DisableClickImageView();
    AStarSolver as = new AStarSolver();
    as.solvePuzzle(arr, GOAL); //Solve the puzzle
    displayResult(as.solutionPath); //display animation
    as = null;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    copySTARTtoArray();
    setImageResource();
    EnableButton();             
}
```

I want text **"Finished"** is displayed after function `displayResult()` is finished but the text **"Finished"**
show at the same time with  function `displayResult()`.

How to solve this??

Edit:

Here is the code for displayResult();

```
public void displayResult(final Stack<Node> solutionPath)
{
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < solutionPath.size(); i++)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                    Node solNode = solutionPath.pop();
                    //solNode.NodeState.
                    tile00.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(0));
                    tile01.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(1));
                    tile02.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(2));
                    tile10.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(3));
                    tile11.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(4));
                        tile12.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(5));
                    tile20.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(6));
                        tile21.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(7));
                    tile22.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(8));  
            } 
        }, 800 * (i + 1));  

    }   
}
```

It display the result of animation (Ex: tile0 to tile1)

Comment: What are you doing in display result? Please paste displayResult() method here.

Comment: thanks for reply, I already edit my question.

Comment: You are displaying Finished at 2 place, about which you are talking?

Comment: sorry my mistake, there is no finish inside the function displayResult()

Comment: Actually you are delaying some execution in different iterations of loops and then showing toast meanwhile delayed code is being executed.

Comment: So, what is the solution??

Comment: Try this. Put this code after your for loop.  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); },800*(solutionPath.size()+1)});

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48233/discussion-between-adnan-and-arvin99)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void displayResult(final Stack<Node> solutionPath)
{
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < solutionPath.size(); i++)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                    Node solNode = solutionPath.pop();
                    //solNode.NodeState.
                    tile00.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(0));
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    tile22.setImageResource(solNode.getImageResourceBasedNodeState(8));  
            } 
        }, 800 * (i + 1));  

    }  
// Put following code
 handler.postDelayed(
    new Runnable() { 
      public void run() { 
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }
     },800*(solutionPath.size()+1)
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be look like this.

```
solvePuzzle(...){
    // solved #1
    displayResult(...){
    }

    // solved #2
    displayResult(...){
    }
}
```

or use thread.

---

```
as.solvePuzzle(arr, GOAL); //Solve the puzzle
displayResult(as.solutionPath); //display animation
```

means solvePuzzle is all done, then call displayResult.

Comment: Thanx, but solvePuzzle() is in another class. How to solve it?? If I move the function displayResult to the same class with solvePuzzle(), I can't update the image resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
//code of this function

 function1();
}
function1(){
//code of this function

 function2();
}


function2(){
}
```